# Start Android App Whenever Device is Plugged In

Tags: android

I'm curious if there's a method to start up an application whenever the device has been plugged into a power source. I've done a bit of Google searching but all I can find is detecting when a device is plugged in while an application is already running.

Anyone have any resources on the subject?

Comment: The answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217692/detecting-the-device-being-plugged-in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The action for the USB is:

```
android.intent.action.UMS_CONNECTED
```

There's a tutorial about usb connection [here](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-programming-tutorials/detect-usb-connection/)