# In Android, is there a way to use broadcast receiver to detect the switch between wifi and 3G?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, wif, 3g

Using broadcast receiver, it's easy to find out whether now the phone is plugged in or not.  The following StackOverflow question describes this: 
[Detecting the device being plugged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217692/detecting-the-device-being-plugged-in).

I also know how to check whether the current connection is WIFI or mobile using the function `getActiveNetworkInfo()` to keep polling the current connection info.

My question is: Is it possible to use the broadcast receiver to detect the switch between WiFi and 3G? It should be more efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think u can use this in your xml file for Broadcast receiver

```
 <receiver android:name="packagename.classname" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

For more clarrification check this link
http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html