# Receiving Power Connection event

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest

I am trying to learn android on my own, and currently working on a simple project.

I want to receive whenever the phone is plugged to a power source, so I put a receiver to the manifest and create a subclass under my main activity. The problem is the program crashes when I plug the phone.

There are many questions about it here and everywhere else, and believe me I looked all of them but none of them solved this problem.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MySystemBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED event received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
    <receiver
        android:name="deneme.sarjolcer.MainActivity$MySystemBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Please forgive me if there is a too silly error, I am just new at this thing. I have been working over the same error for a week now and actually do not see straight now. Thank you very much.

Comment: check this stackoverflow answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217692/detecting-the-device-being-plugged-in

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen appearently, inner classes must be written with $ sign instead of a dot. Android Studio giving me an error ptherwise.

Comment: @MarcoLuongo I want to create the receiver in the manifest, that question uses dynamic receiver.  When I implement everything else in there, result does not change

Comment: Give us stack trace. We need to see error in order to see what went wrong...

Comment: @BozicNebojsa Really sorry but I'm a newbie, so please help me, how can I print the trace of the program? (Note that I cannot debug it since I have to unplug the phone from the pc and re-plug it. )

Answer (score 0):

```
add permission 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS"></uses-permission>
```